# How to extract certificate from .p12 (PFX) file using KEYTOOL commands

Tags: ssl, certificate, keytool, pfx

I want to extract certificate from a `.p12` file. I can't use `openssl` as it is not allowed in my organization.

Is `keytool` able to extract the certificate, or is there any other way by which I can get this certificate extracted?

Do I require the password for the private key for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use this Keytool command to export certificate from a KeyStore.

> keytool -exportcert -keystore KEYSTORE_ABSOLUTE_PATH.p12
>   -storetype PKCS12 -storepass KEYSTORE_PASSWORD -alias ALIAS -file EXPORTED_CERT_NAME.crt

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer will give you a certificate in **binary** format. If you want the resulting certificate to be in **[PEM format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1421) i.e text,** add the `keytool` option `-rfc` like so:

`keytool -exportcert -rfc` //+ other options

> -rfc – Will output in PEM format as defined by RFC 1421.

#### Result

This will give you a readable certificate
 `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`
*body*
`-----END CERTIFICATE-----`.